The relation between nonadjacency preserving map and fractional chromatic number
In the paper "Graph information ratio", $\phi:V(G^k)\to V(H^n)$ is nonadjacency preserving if for any $g\not\sim g'$, $\phi(g)\not\sim \phi(g')$, $\not\sim$ means not adjacent and distinct. The fractional chromatic number of $\overline{G}$ is $\overline{\chi}_{f}(G)=\lim_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[k]{\chi(\overline{G}^{\vee k})}=\chi_{f}(\overline{G})$.
In the proof of Theorem 2.13, "We map $F^{k_{1}}$ to an empty graph with $\binom{n}{\alpha n}$ vertices. This can be done if $k_{1}\log\overline{\chi}_{f}(F)\leq \log\binom{n}{\alpha n}$." Here $\alpha$ is such that $\alpha n\in \{0,1,\ldots,n\}$.
I think the map here is nonadjacency preserving. Why is it true that if $k_{1}\log\overline{\chi}_{f}(F)\leq \log\binom{n}{\alpha n}$, then there is a nonadjacency preserving map from $F^{k_{1}}$ to $\overline{K_{\binom{n}{\alpha n}}}$?

Do you happen to know if this is an alternate definition of the usual notion of fractional chromatic number (Wikipedia link) or if it's unrelated?

@MishaLavrov Based on Fractional Graph Theory by Scheinerman and Ullman, Corollary 3.4.3, $\overline{\chi}f(G)=\chi{f}(\overline{G})$, where $\chi_{f}$ is the usual definition of fractional chromatic number.

The inequality $k_{1} \log \overline{\chi}_{f}(F) \le \log \binom{n}{\alpha n}$ guarantees that there are enough vertices in $\overline{K_{m}}$ (where $m = \binom{n}{\alpha n}$) to accommodate all possible colorings of $F^{k_{1}}$. Since $\overline{K_{m}}$ has no edges, any mapping from the colorings of $F^{k_{1}}$ to the vertices of $\overline{K_{m}}$ will be non-adjacency preserving.
We are given that $k_{1} \log \overline{\chi}_{f}(F) \le \log \binom{n}{\alpha n}$. This inequality involves logarithms, so let's rewrite it in exponential form.
The inequality $k_{1} \log \overline{\chi}_{f}(F) \le \log \binom{n}{\alpha n}$ is equivalent to $\overline{\chi}_{f}(F)^{k_{1}} \le \binom{n}{\alpha n}$.
The expression $\binom{n}{\alpha n}$ represents the number of vertices in the empty graph $\overline{K_{m}}$ where $m = \binom{n}{\alpha n}$. This is because an empty graph on $m$ vertices has no edges, and $\binom{n}{\alpha n}$ counts the number of ways to choose $\alpha n$ vertices from a set of $n$ vertices.
The fractional chromatic number $\overline{\chi}_{f}(F)$ is a lower bound on the chromatic number of the complement of graph $F$, denoted as $\overline{\chi}(F)$. This means that any proper coloring of $\overline{F}$ requires at least $\overline{\chi}_{f}(F)$ colors.
The expression $\overline{\chi}_{f}(F)^{k_{1}}$ represents the number of possible colorings of the vertices of $F^{k_{1}}$ using $\overline{\chi}_{f}(F)$ colors. Each vertex in $F^{k_{1}}$ is a $k_{1}$-tuple of vertices from $F$.
The inequality $\overline{\chi}_{f}(F)^{k_{1}} \le \binom{n}{\alpha n}$ implies that the number of possible colorings of $F^{k_{1}}$ is less than or equal to the number of vertices in $\overline{K_{m}}$ where $m = \binom{n}{\alpha n}$.
Since the number of colorings of $F^{k_{1}}$ is less than or equal to the number of vertices in $\overline{K_{m}}$, we can map each coloring of $F^{k_{1}}$ to a distinct vertex in $\overline{K_{m}}$. This mapping is non-adjacency preserving because $\overline{K_{m}}$ has no edges, so no two vertices are adjacent. Therefore, any mapping from the colorings of $F^{k_{1}}$ to the vertices of $\overline{K_{m}}$ will automatically be non-adjacency preserving.

Why is $\overline{\chi}f(F)^{k_1}$ the number of possible colorings of the vertices of $F^{k{1}}$ using $\overline{\chi}_f(F)$ colors? Also in the last paragraph, why do we map each coloring of $F^{k_1}$ to a vertex in $\overline{K_m}$?
